# Unable to create bucket in google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I want to create bucket in google cloud with Python.

My service account key has the following format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-15891817892",
  "private_key_id": "89347sdjlf56khk",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nabcdefghi==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "starting-account-dslkfjal983475sd@project-15891817892.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "729387492879034579812",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/starting-account-dslkfjal983475sd%40project-15891817892.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I have added the following roles:

```
Actions Admin
AutoML Admin
Bigtable Administrator
Cloud Data Fusion Admin
Service Account Admin
Owner
Cloud Run Admin
Service Broker Admin
Service Usage Admin
Storage Admin
Storage HMAC Key Admin
Storage Object Admin
Storage Object Creator
Storage Transfer Admi
```

Here is the python code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = r'C:\project-934875sddklf32.json'
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'data'
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
```

However, I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    list_buckets()
  File "C:\gcloud\test.py", line 109, in list_buckets
    for bucket in buckets:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\page_iterator.py", line 204, in _items_iter
    for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\page_iterator.py", line 235, in _page_iter
    page = self._next_page()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\page_iterator.py", line 361, in _next_page
    response = self._get_next_page_response()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\page_iterator.py", line 411, in _get_next_page_response
    method=self._HTTP_METHOD, path=self.path, query_params=params
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\_http.py", line 393, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project-89324y9sdhfks&projection=noAcl: starting-account-934875dlkjfls@project-jsdlkjf9ulsj.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 2093472972.
```

Why does this error occur and how to solve it?

Comment: Note: your service account names don't match. If you were just anonymizing them by hand, don't worry about it, but the error message says you're using `starting-account-934875dlkjfls@something` and the JSON file you posted is for `starting-account-dslkfjal983475sd@somerthing`, so I think maybe you're giving permissions to the wrong account.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your error message

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project-89324y9sdhfks&projection=noAcl: starting-account-934875dlkjfls@project-jsdlkjf9ulsj.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 2093472972.

Note the project name:

> https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project-89324y9sdhfks&

It's not the same as your service account key file: `project-15891817892`

Your issue is the following: In your environment (cloud shell (I tested on it) or your computer) you have a default project defined in gcloud SDK. You can see it with this command: `gcloud config list`

You have 2 solutions to solve this:

- When you create your client, add the project name

```
storage_client = storage.Client('<your project id>')
```

- When you run your script, be sure that gcloud SDK don't have defined default project, run this:

```
gcloud config unset project
```

Your current code works in blank environment (like in a docker container) but not in a dev environment with predefined default project

**UPDATE**

The bucket name must be globally unique, among all customer of GCP. `data` bucket name is too common. Try something unique with naming convention or by prefixing by your projectId.

Comment: The output of `gcloud config list` is:


C:\>gcloud config list
[core]
account = my_email_id@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False

Your active configuration is: [default]

Comment: After running `gcloud config unset project` in command prompt, I run the code : 

storage_client = storage.Client('<my project id>')

bucket_name = 'data'

bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)

But it gives Forbidden: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=<my project id> <my client email> not have storage.buckets.create access to project 930817954333

Comment: If you unset your project in gcloud SDK, you can use your code as is, without modification. The project of the service account will be take into account.

Comment: What is `project 930817954333`?

Comment: hmm, what is your bucket name? Remainder, the bucket is a global ressource, and it has to be unique, in the whole world, among all the Google Cloud customer. Don't try to create a bucket `test` for example!

Comment: In fact, I have no bucket name yet. I want to create one but it said I have no create access of `project 930817954333`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this line `bucket_name = 'data'`. As I said, the name of the bucket must be **globally** unique. `data` is too common. Try by prefixing by your projectId: `project-15891817892-data`. It will work.